# Cannot use javascript function after script loaded using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript, papaparse

I'm trying to programmatically load a local javascript file - [papaparse library](https://github.com/mholt/PapaParse/blob/master/papaparse.min.js), and then use one of its functions:

```
$.getScript("./Content/Scripts/papaparse.js", function () {
    console.log("Papaparse loaded successfully");
    Papa.parse(file, { skipEmptyLines: true, header: false, complete: completeCallback });
});
```

The script loaded successfully, but calling the **parse** method throws an error:

> ReferenceError: Papa is not defined

Within *papaparse* library, **Papa** defined as follows:

```
(function (global) {
    "use strict";

    var Papa = {};
    Papa.parse = someFunction;
    .
    .
    global.Papa = Papa;
}
```

If that helps, this entire code is called from a typescript file.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Add `(Papa)` in the callback function.

Comment: @Jai thanks, but didn't help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Castro pointed out in his answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38188243/3596887) that according to offical documentation of Jquery's [`getScript`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/)

> The callback of getScript method is fired once the script has been **loaded but not necessarily executed.**

That means when `getScript`'s callback function is called then the target script  is only being loaded in current page context **not fully executed** so you need to give some time to JavaScript engine to execute that script.
How could you give that time. Hmm one of the options is `setTimeout/setInterval`.

You could use `setTimeout/setInterval` right inside callback function of getScript.

Modified version of your code would look like :-

```
$.getScript("./Content/Scripts/papaparse.js", function () {
    console.log("Papaparse loaded successfully");
    function dealWithPapa() {
       Papa.parse(file, { skipEmptyLines: true, header: false, complete: completeCallback });
    }
    //regularly check after 100ms whether Papa is loaded or not
    var interval = setInterval(function() {
        if(Papa !== undefined) {
            //once we have reference to Papa clear this interval
            clearInterval(interval);
            dealWithPapa();
        }       
    },100);

});
```

I hope that would clear your doubt.

Answer (score 0):

According to https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/:

> The callback is fired once the script has been loaded but not necessarily executed.

You might need to use a `setTimeout(300, function(){...})` to wait for it to execute.

Comment: Thanks, but didn't help